# Adding arrows to switches

Tags: circuitikz

I would like to add arrows to my open and closed switches. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5]
\draw (0,0) to [short] (0,2)
to[short,-o](0.75,2);
\draw[ very thick](0.78,2)-- +(30:0.46);
\draw (1.25,2)to[short,o-](2,2)
to [short](2,0)
to [short,-o](1.25,0);
\draw [very thick] (1.22,0)--(0.77,0);
\draw (0.75,0)to [short,o-](0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: Switches]

[image: Switches with arrows]

Comment: CircuiTikz has defined three (four with push button) kind of switches. See package manual  on page 17: `draw (...)  to[cspst] (...)` and  `draw (...)  to[ospst] (...)`.

Comment: The closing switch is fine. However I don't like that the opening switch is shown as already open. Is there a way to change it to closed? I like my switches better, just need arrows.

Answer (score 1):

On  TikZ way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,backgrounds]

    \begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=1.5,
    > = {Circle[length=1.6mm,fill=white]}
                    ]
\draw[->,shorten >=-0.8mm]  (0.00,0) |-   (0.75,2);
\draw[<->]                  (1.25,2) -|   (2,0) -- (1.25,0);
\draw[<-,shorten <=-0.8mm]  (0.75,0) --   (0,0);(0.75,0) --   (0,0);
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \draw[very thick]   (0.75,2) -- + ( 30:0.5)
                        (1.25,0) -- + (180:0.5);
\draw[-{Straight Barb[]}]% arrows of switch   
    (0.75,2) + (+45:0.25) arc (45:-45:2.5mm);
\draw[-{Straight Barb[]}]% arrows of switch 
    (0.75,0) + (-45:0.25) arc (-45:45:2.5mm);

\end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

**Supplement:** For arrows with triangle shape you can select one of many oprions, which offer `arrows.meta` library. With help of library `bending` you can add to arrows option `flex`, which better determine direction of arrow's head:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
    \usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,backgrounds,bending]

    \begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[
    > = {Circle[length=1.6mm,fill=white]}
                    ]
\draw[->,shorten >=-0.8mm]  (0.00,0) |-   (0.75,2);
\draw[<->]                  (1.25,2) -|   (2,0) -- (1.25,0);
\draw[<-,shorten <=-0.8mm]  (0.75,0) --   (0,0);
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \draw[very thick]   (0.75,2) -- + ( 30:0.5)
                        (1.25,0) -- + (180:0.5);
\draw[-{Triangle[angle=60:3pt,flex]}]
    (0.75,2) + (+60:0.3) arc (60:-45:3mm);
\draw[-{Triangle[angle=60:3pt,flex]}]
    (0.75,0) + (-45:0.3) arc (-45:45:3mm);
\end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

Above code generate the following picture:

[image]

Comment: That's really good! Thanks. I can't find how to change the arrow heads to filled in black triangles instead of just two lines. Is this possible?

Comment: @John, of course it is possible. Overview of arrows is in TikZ manual, page 202 -- 2013. From your description I guess that you looking for something as `\draw[-{Triangle[angle=60:3pt,flex]}]     (0.75,2) + (+60:0.25) arc (60:-45:2.5mm);`. For it use you need to add library banding. I will upgrade my answer.